# Ignore commented out file header information in Git

Tags: git, version-control

In my coding projects, each file usually has a commented out header part that contains some information regarding the file, including the current project version. Whenever I release a new version of the project, I need to update the version information in all files.

My problem is the following: when I check for file changes between different commits, it naturally shows that every single file in the project has changed, which makes it really hard to spot actual changes. Is there a way to ignore changes to the header part of the files? I am looking for something like a git tag or keyword to place on any line I need to ignore, something along the lines of:

```
/* <gitignore> Project Version: 10.6 </gitignore> */
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Keyword Expansion](http://git-scm.com/book/ch7-2.html#Keyword-Expansion). But, in general, I wouldn't make inserting version numbers part of version control but rather make it a part of your release process.

Comment: I'd say git keyword expansion has less value than cvs or svn keyword expansion... but they have no value either.  At least in svn you can see the date and rev number, in git you just get the hash - no way to determine anything about it

Comment: @Matt, I'm with Edward on this: it's simpler to make a program that works through the clean check out which represents the code which is about to be relased, finds and replaces certain keywords in the files.

Answer (score 6):

`git` already keeps track of version information, as you probably already know. Trying to keep comments like this up-to-date can be a hassle and it is easy to miss something or otherwise let them get out of sync. I suggest that you remove this information from the files themselves and use `git tag` to mark a commit as a release version.

Comment: Can't upvote this enough. If you're constructing useful commit messages, `git log -- <file>` is all you'll ever need.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Maintaining the file's header information is a requirement of my client.